# I got a problem in opening PowerPoint presentation by nodejs and slideshowjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I was adding skills for Alexa to be able to control PowerPoint presentation using voice commands. To achieve that I use nodejs to run javascript code, but when I did it, `show` command did nothing. See the next link, where I copied the solution. 
https://medium.com/@ferrygunawan/controlling-powerpoint-slideshow-with-alexa-8b44c1e99a4b

Comment: Show us you efforts. Any code? What did you try?

Comment: Have you used `slideshow js` library to control PowerPoint how described in the article? And please, show us your solution, and what exactly didn't work with error message.